# Jaxb XML binding file generator from annotations?

Tags: jaxb, generator

I am working on project in which we need get rid of all JAXB annotations for readability sake and write XML binding file only. Are there any XML binding file generator from Annotated JAXB classes to ease my task of writing binding XML ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [MOXy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/ExternalizedMetadata) (this is JAXB extension). Check more examples in Blaise Doughan blog: [Extending JAXB - Representing Metadata as XML](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html)  and [Mapping Objects to Multiple XML Schemas - Weather Example](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html).